Getting data for the deleted pipelines in Azure dev ops
I am trying to call the ADO API and get deployment and buildruntimeline related data from it. I wanted to know if there's a way to get data for the deleted pipelines. Is there a flag or some way to identify that a certain pipeline has been deleted and is no longer of use? Or the does the data for a deleted pipeline just stop coming and there's no way to identify the above scenario.


I wanted to know if there's a way to get data for the deleted pipelines.

When the Pipeline has been hard deleted, we are not able to use Rest APIs/Other methods to get the deleted Pipeline information.
When the Pipeline has been soft deleted, we can use the following Rest API to get the soft deleted pipeline info.
Get: https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_build/deleted?__rt=fps&__ver=2.0

The above Rest Api is not public. We can get it from the Browser Network trace.
The Public Rest API: Definitions - Get doesn't support showing all deleted pipelines data. If the pipelines are deleted, the data for  deleted pipelines will stop coming.
To determine if the Pipeline is hard delete or not, you can navigate to Pipelines -> View Deleted Pipeline option and check if the pipelines are exists in the soft-delete pipeline list.
For example:

